# Django GAE cron giving DeadlineExceededError

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I'm running Django 1.5 on GAE. I have a cron job that goes over several thousands of urls and grabs their "likes" count and saves it into DB. It can take easily more than 10 min to complete it. It works when I run it locally as a normal linux cron but fails with this error on GAE:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 266, in Handle
    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.5/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 175, in get_response
    signals.got_request_exception.send(sender=self.__class__, request=request)
DeadlineExceededError
```

My setup:

app.yaml:

```
- url: /tasks/*
  script: myproject.wsgi.application
  login: admin
```

cron.yaml:

```
- description: update_facebook_resource
  url: /tasks/update_facebook_resource
  schedule: every day 04:05
  timezone: Europe/Berlin
```

views.py

```
def update_facebook_resource(request):
    resources = Resource.objects.filter(inactive=0).order_by('id')
    url_start = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select++total_count+from+link_stat+where+url%3D"
    url_end = "&access_token=..."

    for item in resources:
        url = item.link
        url_final = url_start+ "%22" + url + "%22" + url_end
        data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url_final))
        likes = data["data"][0]["total_count"]
        query = Resource.objects.get(id=item.id)
        query.facebook_likes = likes
        query.save(update_fields=['facebook_likes'])
    return http.HttpResponse('ok')
```

what and how should I change so GAE lets me complete it? I've read this https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors but it doesn't give me what I need really.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a question of just getting GAE to let you complete the function. When developing for App Engine, you do need to think in a slightly different way, precisely because of things like the request deadline. In your case, you need to break the task up into chunks, and process each of those chunks individually.

You don't say if you're using django-nonrel with the GAE datastore, or if you're using Cloud SQL and therefore the standard Django API. If the former, you can use [query cursors](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#cursors) to keep track of your progress through the Resources. After each chunk, you can use [deferred tasks](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push#Python_Deferred_tasks) to trigger the next chunk, passing it the cursor so it picks up where the last one left off.